# Not showing photos in the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, jsx

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c8Zc.jpg)
hello
I want to add images to my project through img tags, and I coded it like this, but it doesn't show... I want the image folder to be inside the public folder... Thank you for your help.

Not showing photos in the project

Comment: what it's showing?

Comment: Include your code as text not as photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import your image as a `component` and use it in your JSX:

```js
import { ReactComponent as SamImage } from "../asset/image/sam.png";
//Rest of your code...
export default function company(){
  return(
    <SamImage />
)}
```